# App Intents with dynamic parameters. SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, appintents

I am almost new to coding and I need to make an app that uses AppIntents.
I would like that the intent used an array of elements to change a Text. Lets say that the array is an array of strings:
["Mountain", "Car", "Ball"]
If I tell Siri: "Hey Siri, set the text to Ball" the intent should change the text to "Ball". If I tell Siri: "Hey Siri, set the text to "Mountain" the intent should change the to "Mountain"

```
struct chooseWord: AppIntent {
    @Parameter(title: "Word")
    var word: String
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Change the text"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Changes the text on screen")
    
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("Changes the word to ...")
    }
    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {

        return .result(dialog: "Done!")
    }
}
```

This is the basic Intent code.
Hope you can help me.
Sorry if I misspelled something or I use bad grammar, English is not my first language.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You basically have two options to feed an array into Shortcuts. If you array is a *fixed* set of options you should use the [`AppEnum`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/appenum?changes=lat_6_5) protocol. For a *dynamic* set of options (as mentioned in your title), you have to use an [`AppEntity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/appentity?changes=lat_6_5).

#### Dynamic Array via `AppEntity`

Adopting the dynamic `AppEntity` is a bit more code, though very powerful and flexible. You can find a great example on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mralexhay/Booky/blob/main/Shortcuts/ShortcutsBookEntity.swift). And I recommend you to watch the [Dive into App Intents](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10032?time=587) WWDC session (at 9:47) or check out [this Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/integrating-custom-types-into-your-intents?changes=lat_6_5).

An `AppEntity` has to conform to `Identifiable`, as the Shortcuts app might saves the user selection. It also requires a bunch more to let the Shortcuts app know how to display/name things.

```swift
struct BookEntity: AppEntity, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID

    var title: String

    // Visual representation e.g. in the dropdown, when selecting the entity.
    var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
        DisplayRepresentation(title: "\(title)")
    }

    // Placeholder whenever it needs to present your entity’s type onscreen.
    static var typeDisplayRepresentation: TypeDisplayRepresentation = "Book"

    static var defaultQuery = BookQuery()
}
```

The last line of code shows that you have to provide a `EntityQuery` for each entitiy. This is used to dynamically feed the entities from your app into the Shortcuts app. You can extend this a lot more to make it searchable and add a "Find XYZ“ action as well. Alternatively you can also use `EntityStringQuery` for basic string entities and `EntityPropertyQuery` for more complex entities with multiple attributes. The basic definition looks like this:

```swift
struct BookQuery: EntityQuery {
    // Provide the list of options you want to show the user, when they select the Entity in the shortcut. You probably want to show all items you have from your array.
    func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [BookEntity] {
        try await BookManager.shared.getAllBooks()
            .map { BookEntity(id: $0.id, title: $0.title) }
    }

    // Find Entity by id to bridge the Shortcuts Entity to your App
    func entities(for identifiers: [UUID]) async throws -> [BookEntity] {
        try await MusicCatalog.shared.albums(for: identifiers)
            .map { BookEntity(id: $0.id, title: $0.title) }
    }
}
```

Finally you link this to your intent like this:

```swift
struct ChooseBook: AppIntent {
    @Parameter(title: "Book")
    var book: BookEntity

    // …
}
```

I know this looks like a lot and it is! It also took me a while to understand this, but I hope this will help you to get into the right direction.